# Is it possible put a preposition in front of a relative pronoun what?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, what

1. She believed what I was talking about.
2. She believed about what I was talking.

I believe the sentence 1 is grammatically correct, but I'm not sure about the sentence 2.

Is that okay, too? Thank you.

Comment: What you've done here is pied-pipe the preposition to a place where it doesn't quite belong— its rightful place is after the verb _talking._ Syntax doesn't allow you to always take apart the constituents of a phrasal verb and still make sense. That's why your second version sounds unidiomatic.

Comment: Briefly, some verb+preposition combinations are fossilised, in the sense that they don't permit any variation in their relative positions. "Talk + about" is such a fossilised combination, meaning "discuss something". In other words, you cannot here separate the verb from its complement.

Comment: ... Yes, this is something up with which we cannot put.

Comment: @405 Please note that there are conflicting definitions of 'phrasal verb', so much so that this term is eschewed by many grammarians. This has been discussed before. Some transitive MWVs are inseparable (some optionally separable, and some obligatorily separable).

Comment: Note that 'There is the dog [which] I was talking about' ↔ 'There is the dog about which I was talking' are possible variants. But [the dog] is the head of the NP here, not _which_, whereas _what_ is the head in your sentence (with 'what I was talking about' a DO).

Comment: I would say that "There is the dog about which I was talking" is ungrammatical, or at best marginal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to talk **about what** seems to be your main question. If we believe **in what** our brains do, our answers are based **on what** we know and **on what** we read. We carry on **through what** some might see as obscurity and doubt.

Such constructions are correct. In each case the preposition is followed by a noun phrase introduced by *what*.

Your second sentence (as a restatement of your correct first) does not quite fit the pattern because you have misplaced *about*, which in your first sentence qualifies talking rather than believing. Instead, try:

“She believed in what I was talking about.”

Comment: Yes.  A witty (and reliable) response.  Though not strictly relevant to the point of the question, it contains a semantic or logical flaw.  What someone SAYS can be true or false, but the subject matter itself (about which someone is talking) cannot be either true or false.  Since it can neither be true or be false, it can be neither believed nor doubted.  So there is a semantic error in the question itself.